# google vr sdk has no demoscenes

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk, virtual-reality

I'm trying to import the google vr sdk to unity. Where the googlevr package has no demoscenes. Instead it has only the demo.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y70w7.png)

this is how I get demo in google vr how to add this sdk and make it into a  sterographic view(actual picture of the tutorial.Here it is "DEMOSCENES". But for me I get it as "demo")
(the video link of the tutorial 
check the video from 3:45:-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cK1_EnZkwCE )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be one demo scene called *"ControllerDemo"* in the **ControllerDemo** folder and another demo scene called *"DemoScene"*  in the **HeadsetDemo** folder.

You have not clicked on any these folders yet based on your screenshot. You are currently inside the DemoScenes folder.

If you into those two folders and don't see the demo scenes then get the latest Google SDK from this [link](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/raw/master/GoogleVRForUnity.unitypackage).

Comment: Thankyu somuch @programmer

Comment: Don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) answer if your problem is solved.

Comment: Yea! Sure! Thanku somuch! I have another doubt for now can you please do solve it I have posted it about vr Gaze cursor and Bluetooth controller.after developing it as an app the Bluetooth controller doesn't work on the gaze cursor.i have developed an app where if the user clicks on the cube it will move upward.every time .But even if I press the button on the Bluetooth controller it doesn't work.

Comment: You still have not accepted it. By the way, add your code to your new question otherwise you wont get an answer. Mention your Unity version and the controller you are using. Also mention the platform you are building to that is not working.

Comment: hi i have developed the app by watching this tutorial   ( https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiJ5Oq659fSAhWJp48KHeBjBcwQtwIILDAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D_YTVsLnK-XU&usg=AFQjCNFtEpUnde4VhmB0Ui84TAinJ8u8Ng ) the controller i used is vr box's bluetooth controller. ma unity version is 5.5.2 the googlevr sdk i used is v1.0.0

Comment: Hi, you have to post these information on your new post not here.